# Navigation Experimental is not unmounting components

Tags: react-native

I am using navigation experimental for my react-native application's navigation. When I am pushing a repeating route in my stack I am checking it whether that already exists in my stack if it does I use replaceAt() of NavigationUtils to replace that page with the new route, but my component is not unmounting when I do this.

**Expected Behaviour:** When I replace a route that already exists in my stack then my navigation experimental should unmount the current route and should replace it with new route and by mounting that component again.

My Navigation Reducer is this.

```
 const initialNavState = {
       index: 0,
       routes: [{key:'Second',title:'Second'}],

     }

 export default function navigationState(state = initialNavState, action) {
      console.log('current routes:',state);

      switch (action.type) {

        case NAV_PUSH:

           console.log('Page requested to open :',action.state.key)

          // trying to push the route where we already are, no need to change a thing
           if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.state.key && action.state.key)) return state;

         // ensure no duplicate keys

           const index=NavigationStateUtils.indexOf(state, action.state.key);
           console.log('DoesPage existed already in stack (index value if exists and -1 it doesnt):',index);

           if(index > -1)
            {
               console.log('got index in stack, goin to replace it',index)
               return  NavigationStateUtils.replaceAt(state,action.state.key,action.state);
            }


          return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.state);

       case NAV_POP:
                    if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
                       return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

       case NAV_JUMP_TO_KEY:
                       return NavigationStateUtils.jumpTo(state, action.key)

       case NAV_JUMP_TO_INDEX:
                       return NavigationStateUtils.jumpToIndex(state, action.index)

       case NAV_RESET:
                       return {
        ...state,
        index: action.index,
        routes: action.routes
    }

          default:return state
   }
  }
```

Please tell me where I am getting wrong in the implementation.